# cent os bash unrecognized option --system on adduser command

Tags: git, bash, centos, gitolite, gitlab

I am trying to install gitlab on my centos linux sever. I am following the tutorial located here: https://gist.github.com/1601228

Everything goes smoothly until I reach this line: `adduser --system --shell /bin/sh --comment 'gitolite' --create-home --home-dir /home/git git`

and my shell just returns this: `adduser: unrecognized option '--system'`

I can't seem to find how to enable that option or why it isn't available.

I'm running:

- CentOS release 5.8 (Final)
- GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Let me know if I need to post any other software versions.

**How do I run this command successfully or accomplish the same task this command is performing on my current version of centos/bash/etc?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, there is no `--system` switch to adduser command on CentOs 5.8.
But there is a `-r` switch which could replace `--system` in your install script. From the `adduser` man page:

-r This flag is used to create a system account. That is, a user with a UID lower than the value of UID_MIN defined in /etc/login.defs and whose password does not expire. Note that useradd will not create a home directory for such an user, regardless of the default setting in /etc/login.defs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to a CentOS 5 box to check, but try replacing `--system` with its single-dash version `-r` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I'm selecting the other answer because it has more detail but Yours was pretty much the same so thank.